# Creating a Class Initialization Alias with the Using Declaration

Tags: c++, class, c++14, using

I want to create a keyword argument for initializing a specific instance of a class. For example:

```
using My_Word = My_Class("First");

My_Word mw;
```

Assuming I have created "My_Class" with an initializer that deals with if "First" is entered as an argument, how would I make it work so that mw will initialize to My_Class with argument "First"?

Comment: You can't use `using` in that way,  But you can create a constant, if your class has a copy constructor or copy operator.

Comment: You could try to achieve this exact syntax with inheritance, but I think it would make more sense to just write and use a factory function, something like: `My_Class var = My_Class::MakeFirst();`.

Comment: Would recommend to go with a variable that is given around (like a shared_ptr). That said, it depends on the context. Can you give us some?